# Swift 4 UILabel animate Color

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uilabel, uicolor

I'm trying to solve a problem for days, I hope you are able to help me.

In the app that i'm programming i am using a UITextField.
In that TextField I want the user to type the word that is seen on the UILabel.
If he types the correct character I want the character on the label turning green, if its wrong then the label should turn red.

Can anyone help me or give me an advice?

Comment: what is the problem here. Please post your code with error.

Comment: Use AttributedString to set the text and change the character colours accordingly

Comment: Could you provide your code attempting to achieve it?

Comment: Without code, tough to know what your problem is. That said, you'll want to into `UITextViewDelegate` methods and `NSAttributedString`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate# http://ios-tutorial.com/ios-developers-guide-nsattributedstring-swift-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the text in **textField delegate** and depending upon your condition call the function **updateLabel**()

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    self.updateLabel(true, text: string)
    return true
}



func updateLabel(isCorrect:Bool, text: String){

    let textColor = isCorrect ? greenColor : redColor
      let attributedStringColor = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : textColor];

      let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributedStringColor)
      label.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Comment: Check the range....Make the characters in that range green...Not sure about the wrong case.....whole label becomes red or what according to question..

Answer (score 0):

Implement **`UITextfieldDelegate`**

And try this code:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   let enteredText = textField.text!

  if enteredText == yourLabel.text {
        yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.green

   }else{
        yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
       }

    return true
}
```

Comment: He wants to change the color of an individual character, not the whole label's color.